# Software which can add a table of contents to a PDF document

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer

I am reading a PDF book with no interactive contents sections. If there was a contents section with hyperlinks I could click on a chapter in the book contents and my PDF reader would skip to that chapter.

Here is an example (what I want to achieve) from Preview, the default PDF viewer on OS X .

[image]

I need a piece of software that adds an interactive table of contents to a PDF book that doesn't have a table of contents.

- Recommendations can be for any operating system.
- No budget limit
- Text is selectable (but I welcome suggestions for non selectable PDFs too)

[here is the PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8u23fCLc2KkV2NjS1ZXZmwyYUU/view?usp=sharing)

---

Comment: Is the text selectable with the mouse in the PDF? Or is the PDF just like an image (maybe because it was scanned without OCR)?

Comment: the text is selectable

Comment: Any budget/limit involved?

Comment: No budget limit involved.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works if your PDF was originally made in LaTeX:

1. Convert PDF into LaTeX format following [these instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex).
2. [Add table of contents in LaTeX](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/beginners/latex-table-of-contents/).
3. Compile LaTeX and extract the PDF file.

If it is not originally LaTeX, then with similar approach, you can convert it to MS Word and do the same.

Let me know if it worked, otherwise we can find another solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this out. Will let you know it if worked